# Excluding specific fields from consideration in a multi_match query

Tags: elasticsearch

We use the `fields` property of a `multi_match` query to include certain fields by wildcard.  For example, we often want to construct a query that searches only the content (as opposed to title and other fields) across the various types in our system. So we include '*.content' in the `fields` property of our query.  However, there are some cases where we might want to exclude one or more types from the search.  So I'm looking for something like an `exclude_fields` property that would exclude those specific fields from consideration.

I realize that one way to achieve this would be to not use the wildcard and explicitly add 'Foo.content, Bar.content, ...' to the `fields` property, but this would be very cumbersome in our system.